# AntDesign expandable table row collapses on component re-render

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a React component that renders a list of products. I am **polling the server after every 30 seconds** and fetching the updated data. However, after every request, my component re-renders and that leads to collapsing back of my table rows.

**Here is my code:**

```
<Table
  sortDirections={["ascend", "descend", "ascend"]}
  pagination={false}
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={products}
  expandable={{}}
/>;
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I have an edit row button per each row, and when clicking that button, one editable row will be added under the original row. At that time, the expanded row is collapsed automatically, so I should click expand button to go back to the editable row. This issue is happening at first several times after render, and after that it is not working.

Comment: Did you try @masood's solution below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a **defaultExpandableRowKeys** prop and setting it to an empty array works for me. Also, you should set **expandable** prop to an empty object.

```
<Table sortDirections={["ascend", "descend", "ascend"]} pagination={false} columns={columns} defaultExpandedRowKeys={[]} expandable={{}} />;
```